# Modifying boost::asio::socket::set_option

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, boost-asio

I am required to set the options `boost::asio::ip::tcp::no_delay` and `boost::asio::socket_base::linger` for a `boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket` that connects to a remote TCP server. I used the method `set_option` in order to achieve this without any problems.

The question(s): once the `io_service` is `run()`ing and the `socket` opened, if I'm asked to change its options (i.e.: due to a change in the program configuration), can I do it with the socket opened? Do I need to close it before changing the options? Will it explode in my face if I don't close it? What is the best practice regarding this?

I wasn't able to find anything regarding this within the documentation.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have done some testing.

Before you `set_option` or `get_option` from a `socket` you **must** `open` it. Otherwise you get the error "*The file handle supplied is not valid*".

After closing the `socket` and opening it again, all options "go back" to default. So you need to `set_option`s every time after `open`. I've found the best place for me to do this was within the callback passed to `async_connect`.

Example call to `async_connect`:

```
socketPtr->async_connect(endpoint_iter->endpoint(),
  boost::bind(&ConnectCallback, 
  shared_from_this(), 
  boost::asio::placeholders::error));
```

Callback definition:

```
void ConnectCallback(const boost::system::error_code& ec)
{
  if (!ec)
  {
    // Set options here
    boost::asio::socket_base::linger optionLinger(true, 0);
    socketPtr->set_option(optionLinger);

    boost::asio::ip::tcp::no_delay optionNoDelay(true);
    socketPtr->set_option(optionNoDelay);

    // Do what you must with the socket now, for instance async_read_some
    socketPtr->async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buffer, BUFFER_LENGTH),
      boost::bind(&ReadCallback, 
      shared_from_this(), 
      boost::asio::placeholders::error,
      boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
  }
}
```